# javascript not showing all alert at a time

Tags: javascript, html

i click on signup form without fillup then alert show one by one ..but i want that show at one time.

```js
function validate() {


  if (ftname.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("fnameerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }

  if (ltname.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("lnameerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }
  if (address.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("adderror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }

  if (city.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }
  if (state.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("stateerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }

  var zipno = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
  if (zip.value.match(zipno)) {} else {
    document.getElementById("ziperror").innerHTML = "*Zip code should be right.";
    return false;
  }


  var phoneno = /^[789][0-9]{9}$/;
  if (phone.value.match(phoneno)) {} else {
    document.getElementById("pherror").innerHTML = "*phoneno should be right.";
    return false;
  }

  if (email.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }
  if (box.checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("boxerror").innerHTML = "*Please fill the value.";
    return false;
  }

  return (true);
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 500px;
  align-content: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: darkslategray;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}

input {
  width: 100%
}

#button {
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  background-image: url("bg1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 1.6% 2% 1.5% 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h1><b><u>
      Create an account
      </u>
     </h1>
     <hr>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        First Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="ftname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
        
        <span id="fnameerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="ltname" placeholder="Last Name" >
        <span id="lnameerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>  
      </div>
     
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Company Name:
       <input type="text" name="companyname" id="" placeholder="Company Name">
       <span id="" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Street address:
       <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Street address">
       <span id="adderror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Town/City:
       <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Town/City">
       <span id="cityerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       State/Country:
       <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State/Country">
       <span id="stateerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Postcode/Zip:
       <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Postcode/Zip">
       <span id="ziperror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
       <span id="pherror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Email:        
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
       <span id="emailerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br> 
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="box" id="box" placeholder="">
       <span id="boxerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
        Create an account
       </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="button">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit">
         <b>SignUp</b>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

if i click on signup form without fillup then alert show one by one ..but i want that show at one time.

Comment: just check with` return;` insted of return false; also change to onsubmit="validate()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your function set a variable to keep track if validation failed, and set that variable based on your if statements, then return its final value at the bottom.

As soon as you return ANY value from a function, it will stop and not run any code inside the function after that point.

```
function validate() {
    var errors = false;
    if(some condition) {
        // update UI
        errors = true;
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In validate function instead of returning in ifs, there should be a tracking variable `isValid`

```
function validate(){
   var isValid = true;

        if (ftname.value=="") {
            document.getElementById("fnameerror").innerHTML="*Please fill the value.";
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (ltname.value=="") {
            document.getElementById("lnameerror").innerHTML="*Please fill the value.";
            isValid =  false;
        }
        //... the same pattern
            return isValid;
        }
```